# Com LEFT JOIN listar os NOT IN

Tags: mysql, sql, join

Em Mysql tenho a tabela `usuario`, com os campos `ID` e `CPF`:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Recebi do cliente uma lista com alguns CPFs e o que preciso:

Ver qual desses usuários NÃO está na tabela `usuario_gerenciamento`, o problema é que a tabela `usuario_gerenciamento` não tenho o CPFs dos usuários, e sim os IDs deles, assim:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Ou seja, essa consulta que preciso fazer deveria listar os IDs `2` e `6`, como fazer? Tentei com `LEFT JOIN` e `NOT IN`, mas não retorna certo.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Faça com [LeftJoin](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join_left.asp) para buscar todos registro da tabela do lado esquerdo e com isso as que não tiverem do lado direito podem ser trazidos com `IS NULL` que são os dados que não tem relação com a tabela `usuario`,***exemplo***:

```
SELECT usuario.id, usuario.cpf FROM usuario 
    LEFT JOIN usuario_gerenciamento 
       ON usuario_gerenciamento.usuario_id=usuario.id 
WHERE usuario_gerenciamento.usuario_id IS NULL
```

Answer (score 4):

Podes usar o seguinte:

```
SELECT ID
FROM usu
LEFT JOIN usu_gerenciamento on ID = USUARIO_ID
WHERE USUARIO_ID IS NULL;
```

*left join* filtrando o que não tem ocorrência na `usu_gerenciamento`.

Comment: Link do fiddle não está correto

Answer (score 1):

Consegui dessa forma:

```
SELECT usuario.id AS id_buscado FROM usuario
LEFT JOIN usuario_gerenciamento ON
usuario.id = usuario_gerenciamento.usuario_id
WHERE usuario_gerenciamento.usuario_id IS NULL AND usuario.cpf = '$cpf'
```