# Dúvida sobre eloquent com Laravel

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, laravel-eloquent

Eai galera, estou montando um sistema de gerenciamento de clubes de futebol apenas para praticar e nisso surgiu uma dúvida, tenho o seguinte eloquent:

```
$matches = DB::table('ut_tickets AS TIC')
    ->select('TIC.id', 'STA.name AS stadium', 'CLM.name AS club_main', 'CLV.name AS club_visitor', 'CLM.arms AS arms_main', 'CLV.arms AS arms_visitor', 'MAT.date_match', 'MAT.schedule_match', 'CHAMP.name AS championship')
    ->join('ut_lots AS LOT', 'LOT.id', 'TIC.id_lot')
    ->join('ut_matches AS MAT', 'MAT.id', 'LOT.id_match')
    ->join('ut_stadiums AS STA', 'STA.id', 'MAT.id_stadium')
    ->join('ut_clubs AS CLM', 'CLM.id', 'MAT.id_club_main')
    ->join('ut_clubs AS CLV', 'CLV.id', 'MAT.id_club_visitor')
    ->join('ut_championships AS CHAMP', 'CHAMP.id', 'MAT.id_championship')
    ->join('ut_transactions AS TRAN', 'TRAN.id', 'TIC.id_transaction')
    ->join('users AS USR', 'USR.id', 'TRAN.id_user')

    ->where('TRAN.id_user', Auth::user()->id)
    ->groupBy('MAT.id')->orderBy('MAT.date_match', 'DESC')->get();

dd($matches);
```

O dd está me retornando a collection:

```
Collection {#397 ▼
  #items: array:1 [▼
    0 => {#384 ▼
      +"id": 1
      +"stadium": "Beira Rio"
      +"club_main": "Internacional"
      +"club_visitor": "Grêmio"
      +"arms_main": "/images/clubs/1/1537880299212.png"
      +"arms_visitor": "/images/clubs/2/1537880338132.png"
      +"date_match": "2018-12-21"
      +"schedule_match": "16:00:00"
      +"championship": "Gauchão 2018"
    }
  ]
}
```

Só que em meu front-end eu pretendo personalizar conforme o usuário frequentou o jogo, se ele for, exibo o dado de uma maneira, se não de outra.

Mas do modo que montei ele retorna apenas caso tenha um ingresso comprado daquele cliente. É possível eu trazer todos os dados mesmo que o usuário não tenha comprado o ingresso? Se sim, como teria que montar este Eloquent para trazer os frequentado e não frequentados (O modo que pensei foi de acordo com o ingresso "ticket" se houver um registro de `id_user` na tabela `ut_tickets` é porque ele comprou, só não sei tratar o resultado para quando ele não comprar :x

Comment: tenta leftJoin()

Comment: Ajudava se partilhasses as tabelas que estás a usar :) De qualquer maneira, experimenta trocar o join por leftJoin. Explicação:
- O "join" vai retornar resultados que estão em ambas as tabelas, ou seja, as pessoas que não estão numa das tabelas não vão aparecer. - Com o leftjoin, são retornados todos os registos da primeira tabela e os registos da segunda tabela que são correspondentes à primeira. - Tens ainda o rightjoin que faz o mesmo que o left, mas ao contrário. Espero ter ajudado.

Comment: Leia: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/348273/com-left-join-listar-os-not-in/348286#348286