# Join entre bancos

Tags: sql, sql-server, join

Pessoal estou executando o comando abaixo porém não tenho obtido o resultado desejado.

```
USE banco1

SELECT * 
  FROM sistema.tb_menus_perfil_params a  
  LEFT JOIN banco2.sistema.tb_menus_perfil_params b 
      ON a.pm_id = b.pm_id  
  where a.mnp_id = 10
        and b.mnp_id = 9
```

O resultado que imagino ter são os registros em COMUM de ambas as fontes e os registros de ***a*** que não estão em ***b*** porem só me é exibido os registros em comum.

O que pode estar errado?

Quando consulto separadamente:

[image: Consulta separadamente]

Quando consulto com o left join:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Notem que no banco1 existe o registro 266 no campo pm_id sendo que esse valor não existe no banco2. Então pq esse registro não aparece quando uso o left join?

Comment: Relacionado: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/348273/com-left-join-listar-os-not-in/348286#348286

Answer (score 4):

Você pode rodar desta forma sem o where :

```
SELECT a.pm_id AS banco1, 
       b.pm_id AS banco2 
FROM sistema.tb_menus_perfil_params a(NOLOCK) 
    LEFT JOIN banco2.sistema.bdo.tb_menus_perfil_params b (NOLOCK) ON a.pm_id = b.pm_id
```

Desta forma você pode verificar os resultados em comum e os que não existem em uma tabela do banco x e no outro não.
Como você não tem nem uma regra para ele, você pode rodar sem o where.

Answer (score 2):

> *O resultado que imagino ter são os registros em COMUM de ambas as fontes e os registros de `a` que não estão em `b` porem só me é exibido os registros em comum.*

No caso de junções LEFT JOIN deve-se ter cuidado ao utilizar colunas da "tabela da direita" na cláusula WHERE. Caso contrário, o LEFT JOIN é transformado internamente em INNER JOIN.

O seguinte trecho em seu código:

```
and b.mnp_id = 9
```

fez com que o LEFT JOIN se transformasse em INNER JOIN, sumindo então com o 266 e outros...

Experimente:

```
-- código #1
SELECT A.colunas, B.colunas 
  from banco1.sistema.tb_menus_perfil_params as A  
  left join banco2.sistema.tb_menus_perfil_params as B 
         on A.pm_id = B.pm_id  
  where A.mnp_id = 10
        and (B.mnp_id = 9 or B.pm_id is null);
```

Outra opção:

```
-- código #2
SELECT A.colunas, B.colunas 
  from banco1.sistema.tb_menus_perfil_params as A  
  left join banco2.sistema.tb_menus_perfil_params as B 
         on A.pm_id = B.pm_id  
            and B.mnp_id = 9
  where A.mnp_id = 10;
```

E mais uma opção:

```
-- código #3
with 
B1_tb_menus_perfil_params as (    
SELECT *
  from banco1.sistema.tb_menus_perfil_params
  where mnp_id = 10
),
B2_tb_menus_perfil_params as (    
SELECT *
  from banco2.sistema.tb_menus_perfil_params
  where mnp_id = 9
)
SELECT A.colunas, B.colunas 
  from B1_tb_menus_perfil_params as A  
  left join B2_tb_menus_perfil_params as B 
         on A.pm_id = B.pm_id;
```

Nos 3 códigos acima você deve substituir `colunas` pelo nome das colunas que necessita.

Comment: Deu certo José Diz. a segunda opção resolveu meu problema.
O pulo do gato foi o " and B.mnp_id = 9" antes do where, ou seja, dentro do join.

Muito obrigado.

Comment: @PauloFelix Os 3 códigos devem retornar o mesmo resultado. Atento que no código #1 há um par de parênteses na cláusula WHERE que, se retirado, altera o funcionamento do código #1.

Answer (score -1):

Para ter os registos em comun e os A

```
SELECT a.pm_id, b.pm_id
  FROM sistema.tb_menus_perfil_params a  WITH (NOLOCK)
LEFT JOIN banco2.sistema.tb_menus_perfil_params b WITH (NOLOCK)
    ON a.pm_id = b.pm_id
```

Adicionei também o parametro `WITH (NOLOCK)` que deves pensar em usar. O comando SELECT permite o uso desta opção NOLOCK, evitando assim os bloqueios com os comandos de INSERT.

[image: Podes confirmar isso na imagem abaixo]